# Number of flip flops generated in Verilog code

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, flip-flop

How can you determine the amount of flip flops that will be generated during synthesis without using any tool?

This first code is supposed to create 5 flip flops

```
module regdesp (PL, RST, ENSERIE, CLOCK, ENPARA, SALSERIE);

   input PL; 
   input RST; 
   input ENSERIE; 
   input CLOCK; 
   input[3:0] ENPARA; 
   output SALSERIE; 

   logic SALSERIE;
   logic [3:0] SHIFT; 

   always_ff @(posedge CLOCK or negedge RST)
      if (!RST)
         SHIFT <= 4'b0000 ;
      else
         if (!PL)
            SHIFT <= ENPARA ;
         else
            begin
                    SHIFT[3] <= ENSERIE ;
                    begin : xhdl_0
                    integer i;
                    for(i = 2; i >= 0; i = i - 1)
                    begin : DESPLAZAR
                            SHIFT[i] <= SHIFT[i + 1] ; 
                    end
                    end 
                          SALSERIE=SHIFT[0];
            end
endmodule
```

This second example creates 32 flip flops

```
module SHIFTER2D(clock,reset,clear,shift,entrada_serie, salida_serie); 

parameter tamanyo=4; 

input clock; 
input reset; 
input [7:0] entrada_serie; 
input clear; 
input shift; 
output [7:0] salida_serie ;
 
logic [tamanyo-1:0][7:0] aux; 

always_ff @(posedge clock or negedge reset) 
if (!reset) 
    aux<={tamanyo{8'b0}}; 
else 
    if (!clear) 
        if (shift==1'b1) 
            aux<={entrada_serie,aux[tamanyo-1:1]}; 
    else 
        begin
            aux[tamaño-1]<= entrada_serie; 
            aux<={tamanyo{8'b0}}; 
        end 

assign salida_serie=aux[0]; 

endmodule
```

I want to understand how can you tell from the code that 5 and 32 flip flops will be generated when the code is synthesized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, in SystemVerilog, all the signals that are assigned (signals that are in the left hand side of a blocking `=` or nonblocking `<=` assignment), inside an `always_ff` process will be synthesized into Flip Flops. So... in your first example: SHIFT (4bits) and SALSERIE (1bit) are assigned inside an `always_ff` process. Therefore 5 flip flops will be synthesized.

In your second example, only `aux` (4x8 = 32bits) is assigned inside an `always_ff` block, therefore 32 Flip Flops will be synthesized.

**WARNING**: in your first example code, A) SALSERIE is not reset (it's not assigned to 1'b0 or 1'b1 under the `if (!RST)` clause. You should reset (unless you know what you're doing) all the signals that will synthesize into a flip flop. B) you assign SALSERIE using a blocking `=` assignment. In general this is not a good idea, use blocking assignments `<=` inside `always_ff` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of bits that are assigned to in clocked processes.

##### First example

- `SHIFT`: 4 bits
- `SALSERIE`: 1 bit

Total: 5 bits

##### Second example

- `aux`: `tamyano` times 8 bits

Given `tamyano` is 4, that's 32 bits.